# Scroll is not working over the Iframe with embedded flutter application

Tags: flutter, iframe, scroll, flutter-web

I have a flutter application which I deployed on a server. On a webpage, I embedded the flutter application Inside an Iframe.

**Problem**

When I scroll the page, After reaching the iframe, I cannot scroll any more. It seems Flutter application consumes scroll events and do not pass the events to the web page.
And I need user interaction with the iframe as well. I have multiple widget like carousel, Poll slide, Horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling inside the iframe.
I have implemented one of my widget with jquery (not flutter) and it worked perfectly.
I researched more than 2 months about this issue, I found the work around for desktop :
s.addEventListener.apply(s,["wheel",q,r])
If I remove this line from main.dart.js, The scroll behavior fixes in desktop browsers But I still have problem in mobile browsers such as Safari.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found a fix or workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
If you remove this line from main.dart.js :
s.addEventListener.apply(s,["wheel",q,r]) then you can scroll over the iframe with mouse's wheel.
and for mobile devices you can change this line in main.dart.js :
touch-action: j, to touch-action: 'pan-y'
Then you can scroll with touch, but if you have any vertical scroll in your page, It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the widget with **Flexible()**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

be sure that your 'scrolling' takes 'yes'.